# "requires transitive" for modules not working on Eclipse?

Tags: java, java-module

I'm starting to study modules, and I would like to try the "requires transitive". So I createad a module for the interface:

```
module interfacesModule {
    
    exports com.my.interfaces;
    
}
```

with 1 interface:

```
package com.my.interfaces;

public interface MyInterface {

    void go();

}
```

a module for implementation:

```
module javaModuleA {
    
    requires interfacesModule;
    
    exports com.my.moduleA;
    
}
```

class:

```
package com.my.moduleA;

import com.my.interfaces.MyInterface;

public class ClassA implements MyInterface {
    
    public void go() {
        System.out.println("in class A");
    }

}
```

and the main module:

```
module mainModule {
    
    requires transitive javaModuleA;
    requires interfacesModule; // this line I want to comment, to use from requires transitive

}
```

class:

```
package com.my;

import com.my.interfaces.MyInterface;
import com.my.moduleA.ClassA;

public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("main java module");
        MyInterface a = new ClassA();
        a.go();
    }

}
```

This works fine!

Now if i comment the line "requires interfacesModule;" on my main module, should't it still work, as I have the "requires transitive" for javaModuleA?

When I comment it I get "The type com.my.interfaces.MyInterface is not accessible".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `requires transitive javaModuleA;` declaration within `mainModule` implies that a hypothetical module having a `requires mainModule` declaration would automatically get a dependency as if having a declaration `requires javaModuleA;` too.

In other words, what you are trying to do, to get an implicit `requires interfacesModule;` for `mainModule`, needs a change in `javaModuleA`

```java
module javaModuleA {
    requires transitive interfacesModule;
    exports com.my.moduleA;
}
```

Then, `mainModule` having a `requires javaModuleA;` or `requires transitive javaModuleA;` can use exported packages of `interfacesModule` without the need for a `requires interfacesModule;`.

The rationale is that you might have a `javaModuleA` containing both, the interface and the implementation, as a starting point and decide to refactor the module that has grown too big into `javaModuleA` and `interfacesModule`, without the need to adapt the dependent modules. Then, having `requires transitive interfacesModule;` in `javaModuleA` allows the modules depending on `javaModuleA` to continue to work, as if it still was the big module.